# Why does the information content of a less probable event yield more bits than a more probable one?

Tags: information-theory

I gather for a series of four coin flips, if we get $H,H,H,H$, this has a probability of $\tfrac{1}{16}$, so we have information content $$\log_2 \frac{1}{\frac{1}{16}}$$

But for the rest of the events in the probability space, we have $$ \log_2\frac{1}{\frac{15}{16}}$$

which is much smaller. But why? Shouldn't a more probable event give us more information? I would think the occurrence of a more probable event tells us the system behaves as we expect and in this sense "informs" us.

**My Question:**

Why does the information content of a less probable event yield more bits than a more probable one?

Comment: I guess this should be one of the fundamental questions one should ask when one sees it for the first time! I found this question accidentally and damn... I should have asked this question when i first learned it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite the opposite. Imagine an event occurs with probability $1$. Then finding out that it has occured reveals nothing to you, you did not already know.

If on the other hand a very rare event occurs, receiving that information really tells you something unexpected thus revealing a lot of information you could not have deduced yourself.

Comment: Okay, suppose I flip a coin ten times in a row and get all heads. Extremely improbable, right? But suppose my coin is actually fair and that event was just a fluke. Then saying $\frac{1}{2^{10}}$ yields more information than $1-\frac{1}{2^{10}}$ .....that doesn't make sense. If I know the system is fair, it doesn't give me any information (in a qualitative sense) because that series of flips is not representative of the actual system. So the fluke 10 flips should give me less information (qualitative sense) because it doesn't characterize the system. For instance, the system would appear to

Comment: have P(Heads) = 1. Note, I am sure you are correct because what you say matches the Wikipedia page and other sources I checked. I just don't see why my reasoning is wrong and I am trying to find out why it is.

Comment: What you receive is not actually information about the probabilistic system. You are supposed to know that system perfectly and then measure how much information a specific event gives you about what has occured. To take an analogy: If you are to guess a concrete $3$-digit code, where the first digit is always $9$, the second is either $1,2,3$ or $4$, and the last is any of the ten digits. Each digit is equiprobable among its choices. Then if someone tells you, that the first digit is $9$, you learn $0$ bits. If someone tells you the second digit is $3$, you actually learn $2$ bits.

Comment: If someone tells you the last digit is $8$, you learn approximately $3.3$ bits theoretically. @StanShunpike

Comment: Brilliant. I get it. Thank you! The analogy / example helped.

Comment: @StanShunpike: I am delighted to hear that!

Comment: So, we always think that the event with a high probability will happen most of the time. So, we already have this information. Let's take Event E which is 10 Heads in 10 draws. Someone tossed 10 coins and asked us to guess what each toss was. With our current information, we will probably predict Event E as 5 heads and 5 tails . Since, they have equal probability. Let's say i revealed first toss to be head. This might not be a surprise since its expected. Hence, no new information about the event E

Comment: now, its revealed that 2nd toss is also a head. This probably be a deviation. Because, probability of Head and a head is 0.25. This could probably hint us that we might be deviating from our prediction of 5 heads and 5 tails

Comment: And then, we keep on revealing events to be all heads. Each addition of head means that an event that has very little probability has occurred.  Hence, giving us more clarity/information that it is not our predicted event.

Comment: @String , Is this how i should think about information gain?

Comment: @InAFlash: Not quite. 10 ordered coin tosses can be reported using 10 bits. 0 for heads 1 for tails. Each revealed toss will tell you exactly 1 bit. Regardless of previously reported tosses. To begin with, you should expect ANY of the $2^{10}$ possible outcomes and then learn information by each toss revealed. If on the other hand order does not matter, we are considering the binomial distribution. That has a different information distribution.

Comment: Are you saying that information gain will be exactly same for each revelation of toss? If so,  I guess, high information gains apply to events that have very low probability of occuring. In this coin toss case, they are uniform distribution.. hence information gain will be same

Comment: @InAFlash Exactly!

Comment: phew!.. finally i can explain this to someone else :D

Comment: @String, Thanks a lot. I was about to throw this topic in the back of my head. You saved me from ignorance :D

Comment: @InAFlash: Happy to hear that! Cheers.